# Multiply Large Strings in Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class, bigint

Here I've got a SafeArray(not that safe but my teacher said it's fine) class and a bigint class. My bigint class can add and subtract just fine but when I try the multiply function it doesn't print anything at all, i've tried debugging and stepping through it but I can't seem to figure it out, been working on it for a while and am hopelessly stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Element>
class SafeArray
{
    int size;
    Element*Array;
    Element def;

public:
    SafeArray()                         //default constructor(with no parameter)
    {
        size = 10;
        Array = new Element[size]();
    }

    SafeArray(int value)         //constructor with one int
    {
        size = value;
        Array = new Element[value];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            Array[i] = 0;
    }

    ~SafeArray() {
        delete[] Array;
    }                                       //destructor

    SafeArray(const SafeArray& rhs) : size(rhs.size), Array(new Element[size]), def(rhs.def)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
            Array[i] = rhs.Array[i];
    }

    SafeArray& operator=(SafeArray rhs)
    {
        std::swap(Array, rhs.Array);
        std::swap(size, rhs.size);
        std::swap(def, rhs.def);
        return *this;
    }

    Element get(int pos)    const                 //get method
    {
        if (pos<0)
        {
            cout << "error";
        }

        return Array[pos];
    }

    void set(int pos, Element val)
    {
        if (pos<0)
        {
            cout << "error";
            return;
        }
        if (pos >= size)
        {
            resize(pos + 1);
        }
        Array[pos] = val;
    }

    void resize(int new_size)
    {
        Element*temp = new Element[new_size];
        for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = Array[i];
        }
        delete[]Array;
        Array = temp;
        size = new_size;
    }

    void set_default(Element d)        //set_default
    {
        def = d;
    }

    int get_size()                       //get size
    {
        return size;
    }
};

int size = 100; //for testing

class bigint
{
    SafeArray<int> *arr;
public:
    bool sign;
bigint()                                                   //initializes to zero
    {
        arr = new SafeArray<int>;
        for(int i =0;i < size; i++)
            arr->set(i,0);
    }

void print()                                               //prints numbers without zeroes in front
    {
        bool start_num=false;
        for(int i = 0;i <arr->get_size() ;i++)
        {
            if(arr->get(i)!=0 && start_num==false )
            {start_num=true;
                cout << arr->get(i);}
         else if(start_num==true)
             cout<<arr->get(i);

        }

       cout<<endl;
    }
    void assign(const bigint &A)                             //
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr->get_size();i++)
    {                                                            //Ways to initialize stuff
        arr->set(i,A.arr->get(i));
    }

}
void assign(string num)                                  
    {
        long len = num.length();
        int j=arr->get_size()-1;
        for(long i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            arr->set(j,num[i]-48);
            j--;
        }
    }
void add_pos(const bigint &A)                                //add big ints
    {
        int carry=0;
        for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
           {
               int result = arr->get(i)+A.arr->get(i)+carry;
               arr->set(i,result%10);
               carry=result/10;
           }
    }

void sub_pos(const bigint &A)
        {
           int borrow=0;
           for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
           {
              int result = ((arr->get(i) - A.arr->get(i)-borrow));
              if(result<0)
              {
                 arr->set(i,result +10);
                 borrow = 1;
              }
              else
              {
                 arr->set(i,result);
                 borrow = 0;
              }
            }
        }


    void multiply(const bigint &A)
        {
            for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
                {
                  int carry=0;

               for(int j=size-1;j>=0;j--)
                 {
                   int product=((arr->get(i)*A.arr->get(j))+carry);
                   arr->set(i+j,product%10);
                   carry=product/10;
                 }
            }
    }

    }

int main()
{
 bigint a,b;
a.assign("1234");
b.assign("5678");
a.multiply(b);
a.print();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `multiply` function, the outer loop, should the condition really be `i<=0`? Don't you mean `i >= 0`?

Comment: yeah my bad. just fixed it.

Comment: Your `SafeArray` class is not safe at all.  Who is teaching this stuff?  No copy constructor, no assignment operator?  And it's supposed to be "safe"?

Comment: yeah I just put the safearray class for context. I know it sucks but it works for what Im trying to do. Addition and subtraction work fine with it.

Comment: @jack: Not related to this specific question, but just wanted to mention, have you considered following up on your previous five questions on BigInt and SafeArray? If the answer(s) were not satisfactory, you can ask clarification questions. If they were, you can acknowledge by upvoting or accepting (depending on how useful it is to you).

Comment: For multiply, just call "add" `n` times.  That would have solved your problem, but you are using the non-safe SafeArray to prevent this easy solution from being implemented.  You also would need to implement the obvious missing functions, like assigning a bigint to a bigint.  Otherwise, what's the point if you can't actually do arithmetic using bigint's?

Comment: @jack `My bigint class can add and subtract just fine`  As my last comment suggested, you can leverage the `add` function you say works ok to do the multiplication.  But you didn't post `add`, so can't tell you any further what to do with it. `not that safe but my teacher said it's fine`  If it's your teacher that came up with the SafeArray class, it shouldn't have taken him/her more than 2 minutes to actually make the class "safe" for you to use.  Unbelievable (shaking head)...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok I've made my SafeArray a little better(sort of) and I added my add function and a bigint function. It's the last day of the semester so right now I'm just trying to put out something that works, the safearray is not part of the grade. I know that's lazy programing but it's all ive got time for, sorry. I appreciate the input though.

Comment: @jack Did you test your `add_pos` function to see if it can add bigint to the same instance of bigint?  For example `bigint a; a.assign("123"); a.add_pos(a);`?  If so, then it is just a matter of implementing copy constructor and assignment operator for bigint, and the rest is trivial if multiply is implemented in terms of `add_pos`.

Comment: yes it can do that. but we havent learned about copy constructors or assignment operators. This is an intro class, can you give me an example of how to implement this?

Comment: @jack I understand that.  But if it is the teacher that supplied you the SafeArray class, they should have given you one with the appropriate functions -- you need not know at that time what they did, only that the array is truly safe.  It isn't your fault -- it's the teacher's -- they're giving you a template class, so there is absolutely no excuse for them to not have also supplied two simple functions in that class.  If you had a true safe array, then instead of a pointer, you would have an instance of it in your BigInt class, and then you would have been almost there.

Comment: @jack see here:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12aead5652875bd7  Note the two missing functions (I also changed the `get` to not set a default -- that can be done in the constructor, and in any event, you never call `set_default` anywhere in your code).  With that SafeArray, you now need only create an instance of it in your `bigint` class instead of creating a pointer.  Then change the `arr->` to `arr.`.  Then things become much simpler (and yes, safer).  It took me all of a couple of minutes to add those functions -- a teacher of C++ should have been able to do the same thing.

Comment: Awesome thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: Also, please post the `sub_pos` function.  I think I can give you an outline of what to do with multiply (again, if you want to implement it in terms of `add_pos`).  What the goal is really to do is to use the existing functions to do the multiplication -- yes, it may be slower, but it will be built on functions that you say work correctly already.

Comment: I just added the sub_pos

Comment: Sorry, one more change:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f22a24e04421ae1

Comment: its cool, just changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the comments and the following changes to `SafeArray`

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f22a24e04421ae1

one way to achieve multiplication is to leverage the functions you say already work, namely `bigint::add_pos` and `bigint::sub_pos` to do the multiplication.  The goal is to simulate `m * n` by adding `m` to itself `n-1` times.  For example, `4 * 3` is the same as `4 + 4 + 4` (we added 4 to itself 2 times).

Note: If the requirements are that you have to write the multiply code totally independent of the existing functions, and/or use the unsafe version of `SafeArray`, then this answer won't help you and you will have to do things from scratch.

---

**Preliminaries:**

The first thing that should be done is to replace the pointer to the `SafeArray` in your `bigint` class to an actual instance:

`SafeArray<int> arr;`

The second changes will be the changing of `arr->` to `arr.` within your `bigint` class.  This should be seamless change.

Now, the third thing to do is to create a helper function in `bigint`, call it `is_zero` to determine if the `bigint` represents 0.  You can easily do this by writing a loop and making sure that all entries in `arr` are `0`.  The function should be `const`, i.e.

`bool is_zero() const;`

The last change is that you have a bug in your `bigint` default constructor.  That bug is that you didn't initialize the `arr` SafeArray to have `size` elements.  You used the default, which is only 10.  To fix this, initialize the `arr` to `size` elements

```
bigint() : arr(size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr.set(i, 0);
}
```

I kept your global variable `size`, but it really should be removed from being a global, and your `bigint` class should use `arr.get_size()` to get the size of the array.

---

**Implementation:**

So now we get to the implementation of `multiply` using your existing functions.  It is kind of a roundabout way, and it may be slow for very large values.

Let's get to the code:

```
void multiply(const bigint &A)
{
    // check for multiplication by 0
    if ( A.is_zero() )
    {
       *this = A;  // copy our paramter (which is 0) to this object
       return;  
    }

    bigint tempInt(*this);  // our original value
    bigint startVal(*this);  // our running total
    bigint startA(A);   // our counter
    bigint subtractor;
    subtractor.assign("1");  // our decrementor for looping

    // subtract one from the number of times we need to add
    startA.sub_pos(subtractor);

    // keep adding until the number of times we've added is 
    // sufficient
    while (!startA.is_zero()) 
    {
        // add to running total
        startVal.add_pos(tempInt);

        // subtract 1 from our counter
        startA.sub_pos(subtractor);
    } 

    // assign the final result to our object, and we're done
    *this = startVal;
}
```

So what did we do?

First we checked for multiplication of 0.  If so, then we zero out everything and just return.

If not a multiplication of 0, we set up a temporary bigint that holds our original value (tempInt).  Then we setup another `bigint` that holds our current "running total" (`startVal`).  We set up another `bigint` that will hold our multiplier `startA`.  Note how we use the copy constructor to construct temporary `bigint`'s from existing ones.  This would not be possible if your `SafeArray` wasn't made truly safe (i.e. you stuck with your original implementation instead).

Now, the trouble happens when we need to keep a count of the number of times we add.  To do that, a fourth `bigint` called `subtractor` was set up, and all it does is initialize itself to `1`.  We need this to help us subtract 1 from our `bigint` multiplier  (this is where `bigint::sub_pos` comes into play in our design).

Note that we had to do all of this to subtract 1, and not use simple `int`'s.  The reason -- if the `bigint` that is passed to multiply is a huge number that won't fit into an `int` or `long`, then we can't use the "traditional" C++ integer types.  We are dealing with 100 digit numbers and there is probably no C++ compiler that has native 100 digit integer types.

So we start out by subtracting 1 from our multiplier.  If the multiplier is now zero, we just don't loop (essentially this takes care of the multiplication by 1 case, but see the further edit below for an optimized way to accomplish multiplication by 1).

If the multiplier is greater than 0, all we do now is call `add_pos` on our running total until our multiplier goes to 0.  We do that by testing our multiplier to see if it has reached 0 by calling `is_zero` each time for the `while()` condition.  Each time we call `sub_pos` to subtract 1 from the multiplier.

Work it out on paper in terms of a high-level look at what this multiply function is doing -- you should get the idea of what is being done (sneakily avoiding having to actually write the multiplication code as you did in your question).

At the end, we assign our running total to *this*.  That's it.  All using your existing functions, plus an addition of a simple helper, and making your `SafeArray` class a little safer.

Edit:
An optimization you can make is to check for multiplication by 1.  The way you do that is to set up the counter, subtract 1 from it, and check if the counter is 0.  If it is 0, then return without doing any further work.

Comment: I tested these changes with your current `main` program, and got the correct output of `1522756`.

Comment: I tested the changes described above, and your `main` function does the multiplication correctly.  So we can assume that yes, your `add_pos` and `sub_pos` functions do work.  So basically, you did most of the work, you just needed to have a better SafeArray class (which the teacher should have provided), and an alternate way of looking at multiplication.